# Provide feedback to Microsoft about MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

*(If this is the wrong place to post this, could someone please let me know where would be better.)*

I don't know if Microsoft still works on MFC anymore. I'm trying to find out if there's any way to offer a suggestion related to it.

Specifically, I've written a missing method for `CRecordset` and I'd like them to add it.

Can anyone point me to a place to make such a suggestion? Or let me know if Microsoft is no longer interested. All the feedback links on microsoft.com are related to newer technologies.

Comment: Frankly I'd be amazed if they took you up on your offer. I'm not saying anything about the quality of your work, just that this is microsoft. Although they are very good at putting links on web pages, personally I have never, ever seen them take any kind of action in response to user feedback.

Comment: @joh: [.NET](https://github.com/dotnet) is open source. [.Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/core) is open source. The [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) is open source. And, of course, [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang) is open source. The latter is particularly interesting, in that it was a contribution submitted solely by a **single** user, and it's now used throughout Microsoft to build the entirety of all new API's. Microsoft are *very* open to user feedback. You have to meet the quality standard, though.

Comment: I know Microsoft have become involved in open source (but to my knowledge MFC is not open source). I wasn't talking about that, I was talking about the likelihood of them paying any attention to a submission using a 'give feedback' link on one of their web pages. They must get thousands of those every day, and if any attention is paid at all it will be through a statistical analysis of the responses.

Comment: @joh: MFC *is* open source, it's just not developed in the open. To my knowledge, there's only a single developer assigned to maintaining MFC. Feature requests are always acknowledged. Whether anything comes out of them is publicly visible, and you can vote on them, too. There's no need for speculation; all of that information is there for everyone to see.

Comment: Anyway, [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) is the link to post feature requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better place is under the visual studio help menu, the Send Feedback sub-menu specifically has a "Suggest a feature" item.

Comment: Right. I've used that for bugs in Visual Studio. I just haven't seen any indication anyone working on MFC (if there is anyone) would be interested.

Comment: @JonathanWood Well, they are fixing bugs and refreshing wizards. If we don't ask or suggest we don't get. I suggested revisions to `CSettingsStore` for enumerations. One can hope,